# How to copy each 50 rows a sheet from a SpreadSheet file with the same headers to a google Drive folder?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I learning how to use Google Script. I'm trying to make a copy each 50 rows of a sheet from a Spreadsheet file with 35,000 rows and that demand a lot manualy. Please, how to do that with Google Script?

In some topics, I tried the adapted code below and it worked for me, but I'm having troubles to get a array of 50 rows each.

---

```
function export50rows() {

  var sheetName = "My sheet Name";
  var folderID = "Folder ID to copy";
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var srcSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MM-yyyy hh_mm a");
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(srcSpreadSheet.getId()).makeCopy("My sheet Name " + data, destFolder);
  var dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
  dstSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(s => {
  if (s.getSheetName() != sheetName) {
  dstSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(s);
    }
   });
       Browser.msgBox("WORKED!")
    }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question and your showing script, I cannot understand `a copy each 50 rows of a sheet from a Spreadsheet file with 35,000 rows`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Do you really plan on creating 700 files just to learn how to do something.  And do you really plan to create a copy of 700 files that already have the 35000 records in them.

Comment: Hi @Cooper. Yes, Sad but true. Thanks very much for reply. i'll be back here again with results.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike. It's all right!
Thank you so much for your time! 

The above script to perform spreadsheet copying, but I'm having trouble getting just 50 rows of data for all 35,000 rows in my spreadsheet.

I hope I have made this sufficiently clear.

Comment: Hi @Cooper

I have tried to apply the recommendations, but with some fit.

unfortunately, for copy just 50 rows creating 700 files the code is not functioning correctly.

Obs: my database has 3 tabs, but I only need one. That's why I'm asking the code to delete the other tabs.

Comment: @Cooper I didn't understand you code for "PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty".  What is doing this?

Comment: Do you have a guess as to what sr is?

Comment: What is the first parameter in a 4 parameter sheet.getRange(?

Comment: (row, column..)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Copy file 50 rows at a time to a new file in a folder**

I made some changes and I did not test it.  It copies 50 rows into a new sheet  insert into a new Spreadsheet in the destination.  It increments the starting row for the data by 50  and stores that in property service.

So you can just keep running and on each execution it will continue to increment the  start row of the data file to the next location,

```
function export50rows() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);//folderid
  const tmpltFile = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.test2id);//templateid
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id)//source fileid
  const sh = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//Sheet Name
  const hs = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  var sr;
  let start = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("start");
  if(!start) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start","2");
     sr = 2;
  } else {
    sr = parseInt(start);
  }
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,1,50,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.unshift(hs);
  const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),sss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  const file = tmpltFile.makeCopy(`${sss.getName()}-${ds}`,folder);
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
  let sht = dss.insertSheet("Sheet0");
  sht.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start",sr + 50);
}
```

- [Folder.createFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createFile(BlobSource))
- [DriveApp.getFileById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid)
- [DriveApp.getFolderById()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [DriveApp makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname,-destination)

Comment: This is still going to take a long time so you may wish to set it up to run on a trigger.  Time it and consider setting up a trigger.  To run it.  I'm not sure if you wil run into a file quota limit.  You will have to check that out.

Comment: Im going 2 try.

Comment: I tried to make in this code line "const hs = sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat()" that take the last row, example: (1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()), cause i need this for iterad in 50 rows cause my database have many rows.. but not worked.

Comment: I don't understand you last column show me what you did by posting the entire function into the end of your question.  The ask the question again.

Comment: I received the "The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 15 but the range has 3015" error message.

Comment: Like I said before I don't understand what you saying.  Please show me a complete example of the change you made and what you expected to happen by posting the entire function at the end of your question

Comment: I've posted. I don't understand how to make for the .setValues function to write 50 rows an array to Google Sheets.

Comment: This is the line that writes the fifty rows with a header. `sht.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);`  This is the line that gets the next 50 rows of data `const vs = sh.getRange(sr,1,50,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();` This is the line  that increments the start row by 50 `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start",sr + 50);`  So that every time you call the function it gets the next fifty rows.

Comment: However, for some reason the script doesn't fully understand this, hehe. I will try to find how to resolve this. I'll be back

Answer (score 0):

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("databasesheet"); 
var folderID = "folder ID"; 
var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var hs = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),15).getValues().flat();
var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd- 
MM-yyyy hh_mm a");
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).makeCopy("Sheet Copy " + data, 
destFolder);

var sr;
let start = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("start");
if(!start) {
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start","1");
 sr = 1;
} else {
sr = parseInt(start);
}

const vs = sheet.getRange(sr,1,50,15).getValues();
vs.unshift(hs);
sht.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start",sr + 54);

var dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
dstSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(s => {

if (s.getSheetName() != sheet) {
  dstSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(s);
}
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
function export50rows() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.folder1id);//folderid
  const tmpltFile = DriveApp.getFileById(gobj.globals.test2id);//templateid
  const sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(gobj.globals.test1id)//source fileid
  const sh = sss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//Sheet Name
  const hs = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),15).getValues().flat();
  var sr;
  let start = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("start");

  if (!start) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start","2");
    sr = 2;
  } else {
    sr = parseInt(start);
  }
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr,1,50,15).getValues();
  vs.unshift(hs);
  const ds = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd-MM-yyyy hh_mm a");
  const file = tmpltFile.makeCopy("Copy Sheet " + ds,folder);
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
  let sht = dss.insertSheet("Sheet0");
  sht.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("start",sr + 50);
}
```

I received the:

> The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 15 but the range has 3015

Error message.

Comment: I noticed that you have not replaced the three id's in the first three lines with your values

Comment: Your hs line is wrong  `const hs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 15).getValues().flat();` It should be `const hs = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, 15).getValues().flat();`

Comment: I don't mean to sound condescending but in an effort to understand where you are I have to ask if  you have ever used Javascript?  My suspicion is that you are going to answer no or very little.   I say so because some of the changes you made make me think that you are not using the documentation to figure out whether the changes even make sense.  hs is intended to get the information in the headers so that we can copy it to each new Spreadsheet.  And the third parameter of the getRange is number of rows, which is assumed to be one row.